# Calculate trips in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets assume that there is the following BigQuery database:

| asset_id | latitude | longitude | trip_status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | **52.1052016** | **10.141829999999999** | **false** | **1638274080** |
| **2** | **52.10512** | **10.1420266** | **false** | **1638274081** |
| 2 | 52.104774899999995 | 10.1427066 | true | 1638274085 |
| 2 | 52.1044833 | 10.1431966 | true | 1638274088 |
| 2 | 52.104156599999996 | 10.143821599999999 | true | 1638274092 |
| 2 | 52.10398 | 10.1441433 | true | 1638274094 |
| 2 | 52.1038016 | 10.1444783 | true | 1638274096 |
| 2 | 52.1036183 | 10.144823299999999 | true | 1638274098 |
| 2 | 52.1034333 | 10.1451783 | true | 1638274100 |
| **2** | **52.1032483** | **10.1455383** | **false** | **1638274102** |
| 2 | 52.1030533 | 10.145886599999999 | true | 1638274104 |
| 2 | 52.1028666 | 10.146175 | true | 1638274106 |
| 2 | 52.10279 | 10.1463266 | true | 1638274108 |
| 2 | 52.1026616 | 10.1466566 | true | 1638274110 |
| 2 | 52.102464999999995 | 10.147016599999999 | true | 1638274112 |
| 2 | 52.102215 | 10.1474083 | true | 1638274114 |
| 2 | 52.101968299999996 | 10.147795 | true | 1638274116 |
| **2** | **52.101756599999995** | **10.148195** | **false** | **1638274117** |
| **2** | **52.101538299999994** | **10.14864** | **false** | **1638274119** |
| **2** | **52.1013583** | **10.149076599999999** | **false** | **1638274121** |

In provided data there is a flag - `trip_status`, indicating, whether the given coordinates have been captured during the `trip` mode.

- `trip_status` value changing from `false` to `true` indicates the
  start of the trip.
- `trip_status` value changing from `true` to `false` indicates the end of the trip.
- All consecutive rows with `trip_status = true` are rows belonging to the same trip

**Question:**

Is there a way in BigQuery to extract separate trips from such dataset? Maybe somehow group data where `trip_status` flag is `true` and return as a separate datasets?

For example, from given data, I need to retrieve  something like:

*Trip 1:*

| asset_id | latitude | longitude | trip_status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 52.104774899999995 | 10.1427066 | true | 1638274085 |
| 2 | 52.1044833 | 10.1431966 | true | 1638274088 |
| 2 | 52.104156599999996 | 10.143821599999999 | true | 1638274092 |
| 2 | 52.10398 | 10.1441433 | true | 1638274094 |
| 2 | 52.1038016 | 10.1444783 | true | 1638274096 |
| 2 | 52.1036183 | 10.144823299999999 | true | 1638274098 |
| 2 | 52.1034333 | 10.1451783 | true | 1638274100 |

*Trip 2:*

| asset_id | latitude | longitude | trip_status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 52.1030533 | 10.145886599999999 | true | 1638274104 |
| 2 | 52.1028666 | 10.146175 | true | 1638274106 |
| 2 | 52.10279 | 10.1463266 | true | 1638274108 |
| 2 | 52.1026616 | 10.1466566 | true | 1638274110 |
| 2 | 52.102464999999995 | 10.147016599999999 | true | 1638274112 |
| 2 | 52.102215 | 10.1474083 | true | 1638274114 |
| 2 | 52.101968299999996 | 10.147795 | true | 1638274116 |

Or, even better, something like:

| row | asset_id | origin.latitude | origin.longitude | destination.latitude | destination.longitude | polyline | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 52.104774899999995 | 10.1427066 | 52.1034333 | 10.1451783 | ST_MAKELINE from all trip coordinates | 1638274085 | 1638274100 |
| 1 | 2 | 52.1030533 | 10.145886599999999 | 52.101968299999996 | 10.147795 | ST_MAKELINE from all trip coordinates | 1638274104 | 1638274116 |

Comment: You don't seem to have anything that you can group trips on.  Is it the changing of the trip_status from false to true that delineates the trips?

Comment: how you can distinguish the trips from each other ? what was your logic to separate those two trips?

Comment: `trip_status` changing from `false` to `true` indicates the start of the trip. And the value change from `true` to `false` indicates the end of the trip. I've highlighted rows with `trip_status = false` in the original dataset for better visibility. Later in the question I've separated those trips according to the `trip_status` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, trip_number, 
    array_agg(struct(latitude as origin_latitude, longitude as origin_longitude) order by timestamp limit 1)[offset(0)].*,
    array_agg(struct(latitude as destination_latitude, longitude as destination_longitude) order by timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*,
  st_makeline(array_agg(st_geogpoint(longitude, latitude) order by timestamp))  as polyline,
  min(timestamp) as start_timestamp,
    max(timestamp) as end_timestamp, 
from (
    select * except(trip_status, prev_status, next_status), 
        countif(trip_start_end = 'trip_start') over win trip_number
    from (
        select *, 
            case
                when trip_status and not prev_status then 'trip_start'
                when trip_status and not next_status then 'trip_end'
                else ''
            end trip_start_end
        from (
            select *, 
                ifnull(lag(trip_status) over win, false) prev_status,
                ifnull(lead(trip_status) over win, false) next_status
            from your_table 
            window win as (partition by id order by timestamp)
        )
    )
    where trip_status
    window win as (partition by id order by timestamp)
)
group by id, trip_number
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

and in geo visualization it shows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An important point to consider is that you have to order your data explicitly based on timestamps. Becuase if you simply select your data from a table in BQ, it will give you random rows. So, in case (such as yours), always do `order by timestamp`.

Here is an approach to solving this problem. First, figure out the previous  `trip_status` against each row from your *ordered* dataset (`lag`). Then use the previous trip and current trip status (based on your logic) to determine trip start and end points. Then use these rows to group the values falling in between.

```
with formatted as (
  select
    asset_id,
    lat,
    lon,
    ts,
    trip_status,
    first_value(flag) over (partition BY grp order by ts) as trip_id,
    st_geogpoint(lon, lat) as geo_point
  from (
      select
        asset_id,
        lat,
        lon,
        ts,
        trip_status,
        flag,
        sum(case when flag is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by ts) as grp
    from (
      select
        asset_id,
        lat,
        lon,
        trip_status,
        case
          when previous_trip_status = false and current_trip_status = true then concat('START', '->', cast(ts AS string))
          when previous_trip_status = true and current_trip_status = false then concat('END', '->', cast(ts AS string))
        end as flag,
        ts
      from (
        select
          asset_id,
          lat,
          lon,
          trip_status,
          lag(trip_status) over (order by 1=1) as previous_trip_status,
          trip_status as current_trip_status,
          timestamp AS ts
        from `mydataset.mytable`
      ) 
    ) 
  )
  where trip_status = true
)

select 
  asset_id, 
  trip_id, 
  array_agg(geo_point)[safe_offset(0)] as origin, 
  array_reverse(array_agg(geo_point))[safe_offset(0)] as destination, 
  ST_MAKELINE(array_agg(geo_point order by ts)) as polyline ,
  min(ts) as start_timestamp,
  max(ts) as end_timestamp
from formatted
group by 1,2
```

with visualization as below

[image]

Comment: Sorry, had to fix `st_geogpoint(lat, lon)` to `st_geogpoint(lon, lat)`, otherwise the trip was somewhere in Arabian Sea :o) Also added visualization to illustrate the additional benefit of having origin and destination as a geopoints ...

Comment: should the most nested expression use `order by ts`, rather than `order by 1=1` too?

Comment: Yes. The innermost can use `order by timestamp`.